# Multi line string separation in velocity template

Tags: velocity

Using the velocity template language and I have a multiline string. I am trying to find the end of line so I can split these strings. But somehow I am not able to find it. Used all the functions like replace, replaceAll, indexof, split for \n, \n, 
  but it does not recognize the end of line in the multiline character. I have this template in the work document.

```
#set($st="abc
def
hij

")
#set($index = $st.indexOf(“\n”))
```

Always returns -1. Tried different things to find the carriage return in velocity template. But does not work. One of the string I have is:

```
#set($st="abc
")
```

and I want to change it to:

```
"abc"
instead of
"abc
"
```

So I need to find the end of line. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution